# Running JUnit with Ant: No XML or HTML Reports

Tags: html, xml, ant, junit, jenkins

I am using the below Ant Target:

```
<target name="test-report" depends="compile-ommittedmanage-unittest" description="Generate Test Results as HTML">
    <delete dir="${deploy}\html" />
    <delete dir="${deploy}\xml" />
    <delete dir="${deploy}\html\release" />
    <mkdir dir="${deploy}\html" />
    <mkdir dir="${deploy}\html\release" />
    <mkdir dir="${deploy}\xml" />
    <taskdef name="junitreport" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLResultAggregator" />
    <coverage>
        <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="off" haltonerror="off" fork="yes" forkmode="once">
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${deploy}\xml" filtertrace="on">
                <fileset dir="${ommittedmanage-unittestbin}" includes="**/*Test*.class" />
            </batchtest>
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
            <formatter type="xml" usefile="true" />
            <classpath>
                <path refid="ommittedManage.classpath" />
            </classpath>
        </junit>
    </coverage>
    <echo message="running JUnit Report" />
    <junitreport todir="${deploy}\xml">
        <fileset dir="${deploy}\xml">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${deploy}\html" />
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

to try and generate XML and HTML reports. But there are no XML reports generated even though the Jenkins server I use, run through all the tests:

```
test-report:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\jenkins\omitted\workspace\omitted Ant\deploy\html
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\jenkins\omitted\workspace\omitted Ant\deploy\xml
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\jenkins\omitted\workspace\omitted Ant\deploy\html
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\jenkins\omitted\workspace\omitted Ant\deploy\html\release
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\jenkins\omitted\workspace\omitted Ant\deploy\xml
 [coverage] Enhancing junit with coverage
    [junit] WARNING: multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit 
    [junit]          jar:file:/C:/Users/jenkins/jenkins-dependencies/apache-ant-1.9.4-bin/apache-ant-1.9.4/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
    [junit]      and jar:file:/C:/Users/jenkins/omitted/workspace/omitted%20Ant/deploy/classpath/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
    [junit] Running JUnitplayground.ParameterizedTest
    [junit] Testsuite: JUnitplayground.ParameterizedTest
    [junit] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,64 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,64 sec
    [junit] ------------- Standard Output ---------------
    [junit] Addition with parameters : 1 and 2
    [junit] Addition with parameters : 2 and 3
    [junit] Addition with parameters : 3 and 4
    [junit] Addition with parameters : 4 and 5
    [junit] ------------- ---------------- ---------------
    [junit] 
    [junit] Testcase: sumTest[0] took 0,015 sec
    [junit] Testcase: sumTest[1] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: sumTest[2] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: sumTest[3] took 0 sec
    [junit] Running com.omitted.coruscant.util.DateUtilUnitTest
    [junit] Testsuite: com.omitted.coruscant.util.DateUtilUnitTest
    [junit] Tests run: 43, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,188 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 43, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,188 sec
    [junit] 
    [junit] Testcase: testGetNextDay took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testIsSameInstant took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testGetFirstDayOfWeek took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testFormatUserDateTime took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testEndOfDay took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testDateTime took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testDifferenceHours took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testDifferenceMonth took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testMaxDateIfNullDate1 took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testOverlap took 0,094 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testDay took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testGetCalendarFromDate took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testToday took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testGetDatePart took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testGetNextDayOrMidnight took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testLatestDate took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testBuildDate took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testIsForever took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testAddMonth took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testGetDayOfWeekIndex took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testFormatDate took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testIsOlderThanDays took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testDifferenceDays took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testCreateMonthEndingDatesBetween took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testDayOfWeek took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testIsBeforeOrSameDay took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testParseISODate took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testParseISOTime took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testCreateDayDatesBetween took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testParseISODateTime took 0,016 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testIsOlderThanHours took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testIsLastDayOfMonth took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testNullIfmaxDate took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testToSqlTimestamp took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testGetOverlappingHours took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testEarliestDate took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testToSqlDate took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testMaxDateIfNullDate took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testCreatePeriodBreak took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testIsFirstDayOfMonth took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testGetHolidayYear took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testStartOfDay took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testLastDayOfMonth took 0 sec
    [junit] Running com.omitted.manage.bl.AdressUtilUnitTest
    [junit] Testsuite: com.omitted.manage.bl.AdressUtilUnitTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,015 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,015 sec
    [junit] 
    [junit] Testcase: testSynchAddressWithNullArguments took 0 sec
    [junit] Running com.omitted.util.calc.FITest
    [junit] Testsuite: com.omitted.util.calc.FITest
    [junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,031 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,031 sec
    [junit] 
    [junit] Testcase: testEAN took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: test took 0,015 sec
    [junit] Running com.omitted.util.calc.IntrestTest
    [junit] Testsuite: com.omitted.util.calc.IntrestTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,015 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,015 sec
    [junit] 
    [junit] Testcase: calulateInterestFeeByMonthTest took 0,015 sec
    [junit] Running com.omitted.util.calc.JUnitEANValidationTest
    [junit] Testsuite: com.omitted.util.calc.JUnitEANValidationTest
    [junit] Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,047 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,047 sec
    [junit] ------------- Standard Output ---------------
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798009932600
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798000428614
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798000428256
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798000428620
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798000428621
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798000428622
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798000428623
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798000428624
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798000428625
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798000428626
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798000428627
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798000428628
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798000428629
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798000428601
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 4012195172451
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 57980004286
    [junit] EAN number must be 13 digits
    [junit] Checking validity of EAN Checksum: 5798000428629123
    [junit] EAN number must be 13 digits
    [junit] ------------- ---------------- ---------------
    [junit] 
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[0] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[1] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[2] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[3] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[4] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[5] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[6] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[7] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[8] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[9] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[10] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[11] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[12] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[13] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[14] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[15] took 0,016 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testValidationOfFICheckCipher[16] took 0 sec
    [junit] Running com.omitted.util.calc.JUnitFICheckCipherTest
    [junit] Testsuite: com.omitted.util.calc.JUnitFICheckCipherTest
    [junit] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,016 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,016 sec
    [junit] ------------- Standard Output ---------------
    [junit] Checking Cipher: 2684014996532
    [junit] Checking Cipher: 660405152
    [junit] Checking Cipher: 33259336900139
    [junit] ------------- ---------------- ---------------
    [junit] 
    [junit] Testcase: testCalculationOfFICheckCipher[0] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testCalculationOfFICheckCipher[1] took 0 sec
    [junit] Testcase: testCalculationOfFICheckCipher[2] took 0 sec
     [echo] running JUnit Report
[junitreport] Processing C:\Users\jenkins\omitted\workspace\omitted Ant\deploy\xml\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to C:\Windows\TEMP\null28497120
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Users/jenkins/jenkins-dependencies/apache-ant-1.9.4-bin/apache-ant-1.9.4/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] Transform time: 1328ms
[junitreport] Deleting: C:\Windows\TEMP\null28497120
```

So since no XML is generated, I wager that's why empty HTML reports are generated. The reason I got the `{deploy}\html\finish` folder, is because the plugin responsible for publishing the HTML report, copies the files to a new location.

[image: plugin]

How would I make the XML reports generate proper?

I am fairly new to ant and the use of jenkins, so please excuse my noob mistakes.

Comment: Does it generate XML reports when not using Jenkins? Is the JUnit version compatible with the Ant task?

Comment: @mylenereiners It worked flawlessly pretty much until I had to move the destination folder for where the reports were placed. All the reports from XML was placed in ../.../deploy which was messy. The HTML reports were placed in .../.../deploy/html which was fine, but since the publisher plugin makes a copy I made a second folder in there called .../.../html/release.

Comment: Couldn't you just clean the messy /deploy folder? Sorry, but I can't find a good reason why your xml is "processed" (is that moved? or copied?) to C:\Windows\TEMP\null28497120

Comment: @mylenereiners I have no idea why the process requires that step, but my guess is that it acts as cache or just temporary space to work in. It's something the Ant Script does by itself.